# Calculated Row in Matrix in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to get some rows calculated according to some parameters. For example, I would like to get average and percentils of all columns. I've got about 10 columns and all need to be calculated in the same row.

Edit: I tried to put in a Table via ASCII, but it did not work. So I describe it better here:

I've got about 6 rows for percentiles and average for all columns. All columns are computed with the same parameter per row, for example average(Row) or Percentile_Cont(0.4)(Row)

1. Is it possible to put the calculation only once for all rows?
2. Is it possible to parameterize the percentiles?

EDIT:
alejandro zuleta asked me to post a picture made in Excel of what I am trying to achieve. Here it is:

[image]

So I've got 6 columns with numeric numbers. So far, I wrote a stored procedure with which i would like to parameterize the calculation rows (they may change) and to parameterize the percentiles. Sometimes, the percentile could be 20 instead of 25.

I'm not sure if this is possible to achieve.

Thank you for any insights in advance.

Comment: I think it is possible, specify details, sample data and expected results in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
OK, it's a matrix of 6 columns and 6 rows. I am using MSSQL 2014 and SSRS. So there are rows with percentiles 10, 25, 50 (Median) Average and 75, 90. 
So can I compute this within SSRS or do I have to compute this in SQL? Unfortunately, SSAS ist not available - here, I would have a solution to that. I also know that it is possible to compute this for every column on every row, but this is quite cumbersome when you've got serveral reports like this.

Comment: For the moment, I've decided to do this in a stored procedure. I guess, that way, it's also possible to use parameters and i would still get the data I need. In principle, I even could prompt for parameters within SSRS interface. 
But if someone has got a better idea, I am very interested to know.

Comment: You can use stored procedures or text query and parameters. It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, share a sample of your matrix maybe an excel screenshot that graphically let me understand you requeriment.

Comment: I guess, I need to use unpivot here as well? Or is this not possible to achieve?

Comment: Was able to solve it with unpivot. Thanks even so!